# Table won't populate with data

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I've been new to programming and I been working with phpmyadmin on localhost. I am making a simple table on a webpage to display data. The problem is that everytime I load the page it only displays the table and not table will load up. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require('../model/database.php');
require('../model/product_db.php');

$products = get_products(); 

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
} else if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
} else {
    $action = 'under_construction';
}



 // Display the product list
    include('view-productList.php');

?>
```

This is the view-productList.php:

```
<?php include '../view/header.php'; ?>


<div id="main">

    <h1>Product List</h1>



   <div id="content">
        <!-- display a table of products -->
        <h2><?php echo $name; ?></h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th class="right">Version</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>

            <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $product['productCode']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
                <td class="right"><?php echo $product['version']; ?></td>
                <td><form action="." method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action"
                           value="delete_product" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id"
                           value="<?php echo $product['productID']; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="category_id"
                           value="<?php echo $product['categoryID']; ?>" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                </form></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
        <p><a href="?action=show_add_form">Add Product</a></p>
    </div>

</div>
<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

Query Page:

```
<?php
function get_products() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM products
              ORDER BY productID';
    $products = $db->query($query);
    return $products;
}

function get_products_by_category($category_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products
              WHERE products.categoryID = '$category_id'
              ORDER BY productID";
    $products = $db->query($query);
    return $products;
}

function get_product($product_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products
              WHERE productID = '$product_id'";
    $product = $db->query($query);
    $product = $product->fetch();
    return $product;
}

function delete_product($product_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = "DELETE FROM products
              WHERE productID = '$product_id'";
    $db->exec($query);
}
```

Comment: foreach ($products as $product) - $products needs to be the result of a query of some kind. look into mysqli or PDO since we see no example of how you're connecting to the db

Comment: Sorry, I just posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

product_db.php should not be commented out for one - assuming that is the file that holds the "Query Page:" contents.

```
$products = get_products();
```

should come immediately after the include.

and your for loop needs the fetch result and not just the product resource:

```
<?php foreach ($products->fetch() as $product) : ?>
```

assuming fetch() is relevant to this type of resource since we can't see your db class.

Comment: Thanks, I had already fixed most of that, not sure what you mean by $products = get_products();  coming right after my include

Comment: I mean that you need to call the function to assign $products, that's all. You are including the query file, right? So naturally you include the file first, then call the functions needed on the page.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work correctly after the include but if I put it under the require it works

Comment: lol... no they pretty much mean the same thing. I just mean after the included or require of the relevant file, so you would say require("your_product_query_file.php");
$products = get_products();

Comment: Ok thanks, so thats working correctly but now above the table this code is sitting there: $products = get_products();  I only have it on my page once, I don't know where it's coming from lol

Comment: well, based on what we see there - it should not be printing the code above the table. That one's a mystery. Maybe some kind of cache thing

Comment: Lol yeah your right because it just randomly went away after multiple refresh clicks. Thanks for the help